# Phalcon how to make auto reset cache css and js files after change

Tags: phalcon

I have a problem with update browser cache after change my js and css script

```
      $this->assets
      ->addJs('//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js', false)
->addJs('/timeline.js', false);
```

I thought add version file with help `filemtime`  function. Any variants?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can always add a time parameter at the end. Every time you deploy your code, or whenever you need to, you can update that variable (say in your config) and it will invalidate the previous cache.

For instance:

**Config**

```
$config['assetCache'] = '20160630174000';
```

**Controller**

```
  $this->assets
    ->addJs(
        '//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js?v=' . $this->config->get('assetCache'), 
        false
    )
    ->addJs('/timeline.js?v=' . $this->config->get('assetCache'), false);
```

What this will end up doing is adding the cache string at the end like this:

```
<script src="/timeline.js?v=20160630174000"></script>
```

The next time you deploy or decide to update your JS, change the value of `assetCache` in your config and you will invalidate the previous files.